# how to know pygame.Rect's side that collide to other Rect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using pygame, python3.9, I want to make to return which side(rect1) is collided with rect2.
I've already tried this but it dosen't work. I just want internal module and pygame.(sorry for bad english)

```
def side(rect1, rect2):
    direction = ""
    if rect1.midtop[1] > rect2.midtop[1]:
        direction = "top"
    if rect1.midleft[0] > rect2.midleft[0]:
        direction = "left"
    if rect1.midright[0] < rect2.midright[0]:
        direction = "right"
    if rect1.midbottom[1] < rect2.midbottom[1]:
        direction = "bottom"
    return direction
```

Comment: You still need to determine if the rects are actually colliding. What is the result you've seen?

Comment: It actually collides. It just return wrong values. I could saw that by reducing frame rate.

Comment: I also use pygame. draw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The side of the collision depends on the relative moving direction. The side of the collision depends on the relative movement of `rect1` and `rect2`.

Anyway, you can estimate the side by calculating the difference in object position and finding the side with the minimum distance:

```py
dr = abs(rect1.right - rect2.left)
dl = abs(rect1.left - rect2.right)
db = abs(rect1.bottom - rect2.top)
dt = abs(rect1.top - rect2.bottom)

if min(dl, dr) < min(dt, db):
    direction = "left" if dl < dr else "right"
else:
    direction = "bottom" if db < dt else "top"
```